# How to assign points to a clus

Tags: algorithm

[image: Clumped points]

I have five points (shown in purple) which are in three clumps.  I want to iterate through the points so that points that are close to each other are averaged out.  So in the diagram below the three purple points will be replaced with the value of the one red point.

There won't ever be many points so I can use brute force methods.

To begin I have a point list: [(6,5), (7,5), (7,6), (12,2), (2,2)]

I want to end up with this list: [(6.66, 5.33), (12,2), (2,2)]

It seems like a problem that must crop up a lot.  What is a good way (a typical algorithm?) to tackle this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? You don't seem to have trouble identifying what is a clus(ter?), visually. Try to transform that informal, mental, algorithm into code.

Comment: what is close for you?

Comment: To determine a cluster it is pretty easy because I know my data will produce  separated clusters.  I can just calculate the distance between points and compare with a fixed threshold.  I have tried initiating an empty result list then iterating through my points.  If the point is "unique" (no similar points) it is added to the result list.  If similar to an existing point in the result list I average it with that point.  The main problem I found is that I am iterating through a result list that could be getting longer.  I know I should not iterate through changing lists so I am a bit stuck.

Comment: kelalaka, for this example close is (say) 3.  I check the euclidean distance between the points.

Comment: To your point about the changing list, why not generate a completely new list of the clustered population and then, when you're done, replace the original list with that?

Comment: I see, so I start with a result list that is the same as the point list(so starting by assuming every point is its own cluster), duplicate this result list, then in the duplicate list remove the non-unique (and adjust existing)?  This is kind of opposite to what I was doing (shrinking not growing) but I will try, thanks!